# how to get valid json response

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a invalid response of some values and i want to get it in double quotes as like other responses my response are:

{

```
"status": "true",
"message": "User Logged-in Successfully!",
"dataArray": {
    "id": 110,
    "contacts_id": 12,
    "email": "helloalisha123452@hotmail.com",
    "companyID": 2,
    "isDeleted": "N",
    "isActive": "Y",
    "Lastlogin": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "memberTypeID": 2,
    "pricing_plan_id": 1,
    "can_trail": "Y",
    "first_login": "Y",
    "confirmation": "Y",
    "created_at": "2016-06-14 13:30:31",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-14 13:31:11"
}
```

}

we can see i have invalid response in contacts_id which simple in 12 and it should be in double quotes like other values have

and my controller code from where response is coming:

```
public function userlogin(Guard $auth, Request $request)
{

    $isVerified = $auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), true);
    if ($isVerified) {
        $user = $auth->user()->toArray();
        $responseToReturn = [
            'status' => 'true',
            'message' => 'User Logged-in Successfully!',
            'dataArray' => $user
        ];
        return Response::json($responseToReturn, 200);

    } else {
        $responseToReturn = [
            'status' => 'false',
            'message' => 'Invalid Email / Password',
        ];
        return Response::json($responseToReturn, 200);
    }
}
```

i just want to get my values in double quotes how  i can do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutators inside your eloquent model or [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

> The $casts property on your model provides a convenient method of
>   converting attributes to common data types.

In your case, you should do the following:

```
class User extends Model {
    ...
    protected $casts = [
        'companyID' => 'string',
        'memberTypeID' => 'string',
        ...
    ];
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use the eloquent model, you can create a helper like this:

```
class MyHelper extends Helper
{
    public static function respondWithStrings($arr, $code = 200)
    {
        return response()->json(
            array_map('strval', $arr),
            $code
        );
    }
}
```

and use it whenever you want. For example:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $array = [
            'example' => 1,
        ];

        return MyHelper::respondWithStrings($array);
    }
}
```

Comment: if  i dont want to use the model how i can do this from controoler

Comment: see my new answer, hope it helps.